# How to produce a LaTeX document with only few selected bibliography entries

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I would like to produce a LaTeX document with only selected references from my database. I only want one page PDF with few reference drawn from my database. Here is an example of the outcome I am hoping to achieve. Can someone help?

(*An image was originally here*)

Here is the code that I used suggested in an answer:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing

\setlength\bibhang{2.7em}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\filcenter}{\thesection}{1em}{}

\begin{document}

\nocite{Clark1990}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{/Users/carletto/Desktop/Papers/Mypapers/paperstats.bib}

\end{document}
```

The result I got was[image: the result that I got]

and that is the error message that I got:[image: and that is the error message I got]

Comment: `\nocite{key1,key2,...,keyn}`

Comment: What class of document should I use? I still would like to have the references formatted in Apa. The command that you suggested I use when I cite in text....but in this case I only want to produce a page with a list of references. thanks

Comment: Any class of document; and no, the command I mentioned is not to generate citations in the text. See the example in my answer. Change the bibliographical style to `apalike` or whatever style you need.

Comment: Please see my updated answer.

Comment: If you add new information to your question, please don't delete the original info; otherwise someone reading the current question and the answer might be confused.

Comment: To suppress the page numbering use `\pagestyle{empty}` as in my updated answer. Simply saying "`\nocite` didn't work" is almost useless. Did you get any error messages? If so, what exactly are those messages?

Comment: Did you process the document using `pdflatex`-`bibtex`-`pdflatex`-`pdflatex`?

Comment: I added the error message!

Comment: Try deleting the auxiliary files and processing again. You are running bibtex, right? In about 8 hours I'll be around here (family day).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use

```
\nocite{key1,key2,...,keyn}
```

for the bibliographical items that you want to be listed without explicitly citations. A simple example using `apalike` (change the style according to your needs):

```
\begin{filecontents*}{aabbcc.bib}
@book{lamport94,
    author = "Leslie Lamport",
    title = "{LaTeX}: A Document Preparation System",
    year = "1994",
    edition = "Second",
    publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
    address = "Reading, Massachusetts"
}

@misc{patashnik88,
    author = "Oren Patashnik",
    title = "{BibTeX}ing.  Documentation for General {BibTeX} users",
    year = "1988",
    howpublished = "Electronic document accompanying BibTeX
distribution"
}

@techreport{rahtz89,
    author = "Sebastian Rahtz",
    title = "A Survey of {T}e{X} and graphics",
    year = "1989",
    institution = "Department of Electronics and Computer Science",
    address = "University of Southampton, UK",
    number = "CSTR 89-7"
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing

\setlength\bibhang{2.7em}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\filcenter}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\nocite{rahtz89,lamport94}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{biblio}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `setspace` package was used to produce double spacing; the `titlesec` package was used to change the section formatting used in the title "References". `natbib` was used in conjunction with the `apalike` style to get an style similar to the style in the image of the question. `\pagestyle{empty}` suppresses the page number.

Comment: OK, I am making progress. Starting form your template, I produce on page with "references" centred in the upper part of the sheet, however form some reason, no of the references that I selected appeared. I suspect it has something to do with the following error message:LaTeX Warning: Empty `thebibliography' environment on input line 3.

)

LaTeX Warning: Citation `Clark1990' undefined on input line 12.


LaTeX Warning: Citation `Joseph1994' undefined on input line 13.

[1{/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./soloreferences.aux)

Comment: @giancarloDiano Hard to tell without seeing the actual code you are using. Edit your question and add a simple document (like the one in my example) showing the settings you are using.

Comment: Ah, so now I see you accepted my answer. Does it mean that my example produced the expected result?

Comment: :::))) Now!!!!it only means that I am a very very inexperienced user and it took me a while to understand How I can signal that your answer was absolutely right!

Comment: @giancarloDiano :-) Ah, OK. Glad I could help!